# Tomcat Postgres Connection

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I'm using a singleton class for a PostgresSQL connection inside a servelet. The problem is that once it is open it works for a while (I guess until some timeout), and then it starts throwing a I/O exception. Any idea what is happening to the singleton class inside Tomcat VM?
Thanks

Comment: Likely the exception tells you what's wrong, so what does it say ?

Comment: Same problem was posted recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979415/how-to-manage-db-connections-on-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no singleton inside Tomcat; that's just the way connections work when you only have one and keep it open for a long time.  It's called "timeout".

This design cannot scale.  A better solution is to keep connections open for as short a time as possible.  Your code should open a connection, use it, and close it in transaction scope.

You should also set up a [connection pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) in Tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea. Just do the right thing and do not reinvent the wheel.

Use a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html). Either [obtain it via JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), or do it yourself (I like using Spring, but if your web application is very simple, it's probably overkill).

Use a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

> and then it starts throwing a I/O exception

Well, what is the exception exactly?

Also, as a note, it's safe to use the same Postgres JDBC connection from multiple threads, but [it is not recommended to do so](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/thread.html).