# SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

**Edit**

I have created Task which contains method which loads the content. I need task, because I want to set progress bar into undetermined state during data loading. When data is loaded, progress bar is set to "1" (completed).

What i want to achieve is: user logs in, but there is no connection so progress bar indicates that application is trying to connect and after a while and error message will pop-up and do this whenever connection is lost user tries to do something. But again, nothing is happening, this time no exception thrown.

It all freezes at conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS), isValid() is not helping.
**End of Edit**

Short version:

When connection with DB is lost, application hangs up and no exception is thrown, so i have nothing to catch and inform user about problem

Long version:

I am trying to simulate a "connection lost" situation in my application. What I want to achieve is to display "Connection to database has been lost" Dialog windows to infrom user about problem. This exception is called SQLNonTransientConnectionException. My problem is, I only receive it during login process. I have login windows, and if there is no connection, an exception is thrown.

But what if user lost connection after login? Like he is successfully logged in and during inserting/updating some table the connection is lost? In this case application just hangs up, it is not responding and no exception is thrown, so i have nothing to catch and infrom user about problem.

Could please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: You could start with [`Connection.isValid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29) but I believe there is a parameter to add in the URI that allows to fail if the connection is closed.

Comment: Have you tried [setting a timeout?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-)

Comment: Thank you guys for tips, will try both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when i put catch (SQLNonTansientConnectionException clause into try statement... instead of catch (SQLException) it works.

Comment: That makes no sense at all, as `SQLNonTansientConnectionException` is a `SQLException`, so the catch clause using `SQLException` should catch `SQLNonTansientConnectionException` as well.

Comment: okey, l forgot to mantion that i inserted catch (SQLNonTansientConnectionException clause in front of catch (SQLException). However now i have another problem

Answer (score 1):

Here people recommend using connection pooling library instead of implementing it yourself: [What the standard way in jdbc to manage lost connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997049/what-the-standard-way-in-jdbc-to-manage-lost-connection). This should handle connection lost better. (No experience with it myself)

To summarize the link, it recommends to use the [The DBCP Component](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)