# Connecting Mysql database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**--CODE UPDATED--**

I'm trying to connect a MySQL database using JDBC but I'm not able to get the connection to work. I'm not sure if the way I've constructed the connection string is right. Here's the code and the error:

Code:

```
    Connection conn;
    String userName = "root";
    String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
    String portNumber = "3306";
    String password = "password";
    String dbName = "myDB";

    /**
     * Establishes connection with the sql database
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public SQLConnector() throws SQLException {
        setConnection();
    }

    private void setConnection() throws SQLException {
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", this.password);
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + this.serverName
                + ":" + this.portNumber + "/" + this.dbName;
        System.out.println(connectionString);
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, connectionProps);
    }
```

Error:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:627)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.source.database.SQLConnector.setConnection(SQLConnector.java:69)
    at com.source.database.SQLConnector.<init>(SQLConnector.java:25)
    at com.source.main.Start.main(Start.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:559)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: And don't use a field for your connection, it's get, use and dispose, not get and keep forever ;)

Comment: @RC Why do you think so?

Comment: @RC: Erm. No. Creating database connections is actually pretty expensive operation. This is why people use connection pools – to have connections ready when they need one.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg that's why we use connection pooling (with validity check). .@EternallyCurious because your application might live for a long time and the server might close the connection during that time see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345133/when-my-app-loses-connection-how-should-i-try-to-recover

Comment: @RC: Exactly. And the pool creates connections _in advance_. And _reuses_ them.

Comment: I think we have a quiproquo here. But ok

Comment: @RC & MarkusWMahlberg. I appreciate your comments. My main problem remains unsolved, though. Please help me figure out a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I did tried connecting mysql with java sometime back. Here is how i did it.

```
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException 
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + this.serverName + ":" + this.portNumber + "/" + this.dbName,
                connectionProps);

        return conn;
    }

public boolean executeUpdate(Connection connection, String command) throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
          Statement st = connection.createStatement();

          st.executeUpdate(command);

          connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Got an exception!");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

`executeUpdate` was used to update, insert and delete from the tables.
Hope that helped..

Oh, and also JDBC driver must be in the program path.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours. Still getting the same error. Can you please ensure, your connection string is correctly made?

Comment: Here is the reference materials i used:
[This](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/kathleen/classes/cs3200/JDBCtutorial.pdf) is the tutorial
and [this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/kathleen/classes/cs3200/DBDemo.java) is the .java file used to run it. If everything is correct, it should run and your output will be that you connected to the DB and table created and dropped.
Lemme know if that works or not :)

Comment: Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai) out.. same exception error