# JDBC Connection pooling variable context might not have been initialized

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

I created a JDBC connection pool (`jdbc/WILLIAMSON`) in Glassfish server using JNDI in Netbeans, I want to use this in all servlets so instead of writing the following code in every servlet

```
     InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        //The JDBC Data source that we just created
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) 
         context.lookup("jdbc/WILLIAMSON");
         Connection connection = null;
          connection = ds.getConnection();
```

I created a class DBCONN and tried to call an object of this class in every servlet but getting error "variable context might not have been initialized". See my code is below:

```
       public final class DBCONN {    
       private static final InitialContext context;
       private static final DataSource datasource;
        static{              
          try {
              context = new InitialContext();
                 datasource=(DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/WILLIAMSON");
          } catch (NamingException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(DBCONN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
          null, ex);
          }
    }
   private DBCONN() {
      //  I am confused how to use this method, pls guide me
    }// ERROR HERE VARIABLE context MIGHT NOT HAVE BEEN INITIALIZED

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return datasource.getConnection();
    }

    }
```

I'm calling the `datasource.getConnection()` in servlet HOME.java

```
       DBCONN datasource = new DBCONN();
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = datasource.getConnection();// I am accessing a static 
       method so warning coming accessing static method getConnection(), how 
        to avoid it???
```

Comment: plz help me in finding the answer of above question ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to `private static InitialContext context = null;`.  The compiler is warning you that under certain circumstances, `context` might not be created.

Comment: I modified but getting error inside static block- cannot assign a value to final variable context

Comment: @Williamson Remove the `final` keyword.

Comment: I modified , in servlet error coming DBCONN() has private access in DBCONN

Comment: @Williamson Change the `private DBCONN()` to `public DBCONN()`.

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592056/am-i-using-jdbc-connection-pooling its written private so I used.. using public may be some coding leakage

Comment: That code is different.  Why have you got `DBCONN datasource = new DBCONN();`?

Comment: then how to use object "datasource" of class DBCONN ?

Comment: You can write `DBCONN.getConnection()`.

Comment: ok but whats d advantage using class in stead of creating its object ?

Answer (score -2):

```
static{
context = new InitialContext(); 
try { 
datasource=(DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/WILLIAMSON");
} catch (NamingException ex) { 
Logger.getLogger(DBCONN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);            }
```

Comment: You should modify your answer to add all details, rather not answer one more time.

Comment: static{
context = new InitialContext(); 
try { 
 datasource=(DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/WILLIAMSON");
 } catch (NamingException ex) { 
Logger.getLogger(DBCONN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }

Comment: Edit your answer and add necessary details, don't comment here!

Comment: edited my answer, Pls try this. hopefully it would work. Sorry I am newbie here