# How to configure Tomcat to connect with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

Could someone provide a few details on how to configure Tomcat to access MySQL?

1. In which directory within Tomcat do I place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin`? Should I place it under `Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\lib`?
2. Do I need to add configuration to `context.xml` or `server.xml`?
3. Should I create a `web.xml` file and place it under `Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF`? If so, then what should the contents of this file look like?

Answer (score 30):

> *1: Where to place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin` in Tomcat directory? Should I place it under `Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\lib`?*

That depends on where the connections are to be managed. Normally you would like to create a connection pooled JNDI datasource to improve connecting performance. In that case, Tomcat is managing the connections and need to have access to the JDBC driver. You should then drop the JAR file in `Tomcat/lib`.

But if you're doing it the basic way using [`DriverManager#getConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), then it in fact don't matter if you drop it in `Tomcat/lib` or `YourApp/WEB-INF/lib`. You however need to realize that the one in `Tomcat/lib` will apply for *all* deployed webapps and that the one in `YourApp/WEB-INF/lib` will override the one in `Tomcat/lib` for only the particular webapp.

---

> *2: Do I need to confirgure `context.xml` or `server.xml` files?*

That depends on where the connections are to be managed. When using a JNDI datasource, it suffices to configure it using `YourApp/META-INF/context.xml` like follows (just create file if not exist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/yourdb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="yourname" password="yourpass"
    />
</Context>
```

and the `YourApp/WEB-INF/web.xml` as follows:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/yourdb</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

If you're doing it the basic `DriverManager` way, then it's all up to you. Hardcoded, properties file, XML file, etcetera. You should manage it youself. Tomcat won't (and can't) do anything useful for you.

*Noted should be that the `YourApp/META-INF/context.xml` is specific to Tomcat and clones. Each servletcontainer/appserver has its own way of defining JNDI resources. In Glassfish for example, you'd like to do that through the webbased admin interface.*

---

> *3: Should I write `web.xml` file and need to place under `Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF`? If Yes, then what should be the contents of file?*

You should always supply one. It's not only to configure resources, but also to define servlets, filters, listeners and that kind of mandatory stuff to run your webapp. This file is part of the standard Servlet API.

#### See also:

- [Is it safe to use a static java.sql.Connection instance in a multithreaded system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/is-it-safe-to-use-a-static-java-sql-connection-instance-in-a-multithreaded-syste)
- [How should I connect to JDBC database / datasource in a servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-from-eclipse/)
- [Where do I have to place the JDBC driver for Tomcat's connection pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161747/jdbc-apache-tomcat-pooling-jar)
- [DAO Tutorial - basic JDBC/DAO tutorial, targeted on Tomcat/JSP/Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your questions:

1. One option is what you've mentioned: place the driver under `WEB-INF/lib` directory in your WAR file. The other would be in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` directory. The advantage of the latter would be that you don't need to copy the connector jar into every single project you deploy on that application server. Disadvantage is you will need to **remember** to put the jar file in place before deploying your application in a different application server.
2. If you need to change something in the default configuration, yes. Otherwise, there are **context.xml** and **server.xml** files with default options shipped with tomcat installations.
3. Your application's (WAR) **web.xml** should be under `WEB-INF` directory in your deploy file. You can look at the accepted content to that file in Java EE's servlet container specification. Usually, you place your servlet, filter and their corresponding mappings in that file.