# problem with connecting to a mySQL data source using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat7

I have a short jsp page that tries to establish the connection to the mySQL database named 'test'. I tried to deploy it properly in Tomcat but with no success. All other jsp pages work well. This page gives an error when executed. I'm still a student & I'm trying experimenting on this. I already got the mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar & tried putting it to the places in the answers that I found when i googled this question. The jsp page includes;

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

Connection con = null;

try
        {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            throw new ServletException("Servlet could not display records.",ex);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new ServletException("JDBC Driver not found",ex);
        }
```

The errors are;

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /access_exp_two.jsp at line 72

69:         {
70:             String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
71:             
72:             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
73:             con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
74:             
75:         }

.....

root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: JDBC Driver not found
.....

root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
.....
```

I think this sort of error occurs because I haven't deployed everything in Tomcat correctly. It would be a huge help if someone could clearly state how to state a resource in the web.xml file, modify the context.xml file (further more I didn't quite understand which context.xml file everyone refers to, because it's different in each answer). This might be a unsuitable question, but please at least point me in the right way. Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *tried putting it to the places in the answers that I found when i googled this question.*

Is the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder among them? It should be placed there in this particular case where you're loading the driver straight inside a JSP.

> *further more I didn't quite understand which context.xml file everyone refers to, because it's different in each answer*

That is only for when you're using a [connection pooled datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-from-eclipse) which is managed by the servletcontainer. But you're manually loading the driver and using `DriverManager#getConnection()` approach instead of `DataSource#getConnection()`, so the `context.xml` is not relevant for you. However, it's recommend to go for this approach. A connection pool greatly improves `getConnection()` performance and Java code [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) belong in a JSP file.

#### See also:

- [How to configure Tomcat to connect with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485177/how-to-configure-tomcat-6-0-with-mysql)

Comment: hey it works. How did I miss that. Hey thanks loads man, I have been trying to find a solution for hours. And thanks for the advice, I will go ahead & study the connection pooled datasource as well. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. The `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is just the container for all 3rd party JAR files which your webapp code needs to import/use.