# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am a newbie to J2EE.I have checked similar questions but nothing helped.

I am creating a simple login application but i am facing the above error.

I have mysqlconnector in build path and a lib folder as shown in the image :[SQL connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of5z7.png)

The source code of the application is as follows:

[LoginDao.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNAXT.png)
This file connects the application to mysql database.

```
String userName = "root";
String password = "mysql";
```

**I have provided the username and password of mysql here**.**Is this correct?**

For this I have created a database in mysql:

```
create database form;
use form;


create table login(username varchar(20),pass varchar(20));
show tables;
insert into login values("nehal",12345);
```

Now the project runs properly but when i enter username as nehal and password:12345, it gives the above error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: It seams you did not set the path of your connection jar file .

Comment: Can you give it a try : `Class.forName(driver).newInstance();`. To establish Db connection password and username should be your DB credential.

Comment: You should edit out please do not downvote the question. That tends to attract downvotes and one reason for downvotes is when people add things (like this statement) that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: Why is "ClassNotFoundException" even remotely confusing? You don't have the class in the CLASSPATH, hence you don't have the jar that contains it in the CLASSPATH, hence fix your CLASSPATH.

Comment: @NeilStockton I am a newbie... How?

Comment: how can anyone tell you that until you tell them how you are running whatever you are running? build path (for compiling) != runtime CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

1 way =>Paste the `mysqlconnector.jar` file in `jre/lib/ext` folder.

2 way => set classpath

open `comman prompt` and write:- `C:>set classpath=c:\folder\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;.;`

in IDE :
Right Click the

```
project -- > build path -- > configure build path
```

In Libraries Tab press `Add External Jar` and Select your `jar`.

Comment: if i am using IDE, why should i do that?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse (check the link SQL connector above in the question)

Comment: Bro,Read the content properly i have done that

Comment: http://java67.blogspot.com/2015/07/javalangclassnotfoundexception-com.mysql.jdbc.Driver-solution.html
I hope this will help

Comment: Please don't put things in `lib/ext` it is not intended to be used like this, and it is deprecated and will be removed in future Java versions (starting with Java 9)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know eclipse that much but i would guess that your library is mussing at runtime. As i see you use apache tomcat and it seems that it doesn't has that mysql jar.

You have to add that jar to your apache tomcat. See [Where do I have to place the JDBC driver for Tomcat's connection pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161747/where-do-i-have-to-place-the-jdbc-driver-for-tomcats-connection-pool)

Comment: Still it gives the same error!!

Comment: You also have to register that driver in apache tomcat.

Example from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@database","username","password");