# Where do I put the JDBC driver?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm working on IntelliJ with Tomcat and postgresql but I have this problem when I run my application:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgres.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) and so on..
```

I have already put the JAR file in `tomcat/lib` but nothing changed.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Assuming you have your app in `WEB-INF/classes`, putting the driver in `WEB-INF/lib` should work

Comment: You don't need to use `Class.forName(driverName)` if you're using a modern JDBC driver (recent download). This might solve your problem on it's own.

Comment: @Ishnark You never ever put a DB driver to `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @Michael-O After reading this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161747/where-do-i-have-to-place-the-jdbc-driver-for-tomcats-connection-pool) I see what the issue is with that approach. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled/shortened the qualified name of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. The correct name is

```
org.postgresql.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure JDBC jar is added to the module dependencies: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.