# WARNING:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting the following error message when I start the tomcat. But the application works fine.
ojdbc jar file is in the application war file.

```
22-Jun-2020 00:39:14.060 WARNING [main] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2203)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1622)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1343)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2197)
        ... 54 more
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Are you using correct version of ojdbc jar?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175611

Comment: I looks like we have to add to lib folder as well? If it is there in application war file is it still required?

Comment: The application is working. The warning is getting printed in catalina.out file.