# Tomcat can't find MySQL Driver

Tags: java, tomcat

working on a JSF application and accessing a page which uses a bean to check some credentials against a database to authenticate a user.

I'm getting a Tomcat error when the page is loaded.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
DB.init(DB.java:27)
Login.<init>(Login.java:19)
```

[Full log here](http://paste2.org/vW7nHfYZ)

I've downloaded the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar` and added it to the build path. I'm loading my details in form a properties file that looks like this:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I can do an `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in my Login or DB file with no problems, so I don't understand why the web app is having trouble loading the class.

Here's the DB.java file:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DB {

private static String url;
private static String username;
private static String password;

public static void init() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/dan/workspace/DeutschAkademie/WebContent/db.prop");
    props.load(in);

    String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
    url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");

    if(username == null) username = "";
    if(password == null) password = "";
    Class.forName(driver);

}

public static Connection getConnection () throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}

}
```

My project directory:

```
 .
├── build
│   └── classes
│       ├── DB.class
│       ├── Login.class
│       └── User.class
├── database.sql
├── mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
├── src
│   ├── DB.java
│   ├── Login.java
│   └── User.java
└── WebContent
    ├── add-user.xhtml
    ├── css
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   ├── button.css
    │   ├── font-awesome.css
    │   ├── font-awesome-ie7.min.css
    │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
    │   ├── global.css
    │   └── typography.css
    ├── css.xhtml
    ├── db.prop
    ├── font
    ├── history.xhtml
    ├── home.xhtml
    ├── login.xhtml
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── MANIFEST.MF
    ├── navbar.xhtml
    ├── test.xhtml
    ├── WEB-INF
    │   ├── faces-config.xml
    │   ├── inc
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   ├── javax.faces-2.1.9.jar
    │   │   └── mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
    │   └── web.xml
    └── words.xhtml
```

Comment: Make sure your MySQL jar is in *WEB-INF/lib* folder. Before re-deploying the application, clear the tomcat *webapps* folder and delete the *temp* folder, then redeploy your app.

Comment: I've got it in that directory as well.

Comment: Make sure that the jar is there when generating the WAR file to be deployed. The problem looks like your Tomcat is not replacing the last WAR when deploying your app. That's why I also said you to clean your Tomcat deploy folder.

Comment: One more thing: This problem is not related with JSF nor Java EE at all.

Comment: I cleaned those directories and now the pages won't load at all. Here's the server startup logs. http://paste2.org/IAtFkDh8

Comment: First thing to do when working with Tomcat on Eclipse: [change the deploy folder to Tomcat's installation path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1012378/1065197). After doing this, shutdown your Tomcat, restart it and deploy your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're confident the driver's jar file is already placed on `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` or `myapp/WEB-INF/lib`, other cause of the problem is timing issue. Maybe when your `init()` method runs not all of the classes have been loaded.

To proof this point, can you test loading the driver class at some other time (eg: create a dummy test servlet that loads the driver class). If it works then it is a timing issue

Comment: Even if there was a timing issue, how would I fix it?

Comment: Initialize your driver at some other time, don't use static method of class. You can create a servlet context listener on context initialized event (http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/), or even try install the datasource on JNDI such that it is created when tomcat starts -- not when your app deploys (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: By "Initialize your drive at some other time", do you mean something like *Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();* ?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [How to configure Tomcat to connect with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485177/how-to-configure-tomcat-6-0-with-mysql)

You are adding the driver to the build path, which is needed for building, but wont help when it comes to runtime.

You can put it in `Tomcat/lib` or `YourApp/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I've got it in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar issue but on copying the MySql Connector jar file to my lib folder things worked for me. Thanks!