# How to connect a MySQL Database to a tomcat server in eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have a tomcat server that is up and running and works fine. The same can be said about the MySQL server. I am having trouble connecting the two together so that I can have the database be used on a website.

I am still very new to MySQL and a bit new to servers so please be patient if i don't understand it that well.

Comment: Use JDBC API, write some code around it to connect and use MySQL Db from your application on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You should have asked to google for that. Nevertheless here some links for you:

[How to configure Tomcat to connect with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485177/how-to-configure-tomcat-6-0-with-mysql)

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-mysql

Comment: May I ask a question then is it possible that a resource on the tomcat server isn't running because it is not connected to the database?

Comment: You can check your connection. Mkyong tells about [mysql connection](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) with an additional test step. You can try make sure by that.