# Mysql Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, mysql

I have some trouble connecting my remote mysql database from my rest web service running on Tomcat. I know this is common issue but I tried every way that I found on the internet. Error is: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in here: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

I am using Intellij, what I tried is, I added "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar" and "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar" to my project as library in project structure tab of IntelliJ and I also put these files to resources folder which I marked as resources file from project structure tab. I can see these to jar file in external libraries. I added these to jar file to .classpath file and in the artifacts tab of project structure I added them as library and also as extracted directory.

But no result, same error again. Where am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am adding whole related code. I realized that if I try to run this code below in an other class that not related with rest web service and tomcat, it works. But when I try it on tomcat, It does not work.

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://(ip):3306/DatabaseName",
                "(username)","password");
        statement = connection.createStatement();

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried turning your IDE (or computer) off and on again? :) But seriously adding it as library should be enough. It is hard to help you without seeing your project structure and/or its settings.

Comment: I tryed it :). What do you need to know? I am not sure what is related with this. What settings should I have. By the way, It is running on tomcat. @Pshemo

Comment: I added whole related code @Pshemo

Comment: @Pshemo It works on a single main class but not on tomcat server. Any idea?

Comment: does your war Lib directory contains the connector jar ?

Comment: Since it works on non-server environment it suggests that project sees this library, but at the same time it is not deployed on server. Work around would be placing that JAR on Tomcat libraries (`tomcat/lib`) directory but proper one would be configuring project to include it while deployment.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra That solved my problem, thank you. I thought IntelliJ automatically does that.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to configure Tomcat to connect with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485177)

Answer (score 0):

Just add mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar in the Project Structure -> Libraries.
Make sure it appears like below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I added it in Project Structure -> Libraries and I mentioned it in the question but you did not read the whole question I guess.

Comment: I just tried at my desktop and it worked. No classnotfound exception.

Comment: Remove the .bin jar as you mentioned from the classpath.

Comment: And yes, how are you running the class ? Is it through right click -> Run or through maven or through any junit ?

Comment: I told about it in the question again. It is a restful web service and I run it on tomcat.

Comment: Is it an external tomcat instance ? If yes, put the file in tomcat lib folder. Else, make sure the final jar which you are creating has this driver jar inside it bundled. It depends on how you are creating the jar, either through maven/gradle and its config.

Comment: I tryed that after Alpesh said and It worked, but thank you.