# Connecting Eclipse JSP Page with MySQL DataSource

Tags: eclipse, jsp, datasource

I need to connect MySQL datasource to a jsp page through eclipse. I need to add, delete and read data from tables. I am using Eclipse Helios, Tomcat Apache 7 and Struts 2. I found some related page [How should I connect to JDBC database / datasource in a servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-from-eclipse) but i dont know how to use public Database().What do i import. Also pls tell me some simple procedure to add and access data from tables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn JDBC first - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html - and then you need to add the appropriate Java MySQL driver to your application so that the JDBC connection creation string can locate it.

Start with the tutorial.

---

Edit:  A very good JDBC-based database exploration program is the DBVisualizer - http://www.dbvis.com/ - where the free version can help you getting started as well as help you investigate database contents and an easy SQL editor for getting the selects right.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to download mysql server and MySqlWonkbench for better UI. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
2. You have to add mysql.jar file to run mysql on your eclipse.
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html
3. Add jar file to your eclipse project

   - Rightclick on your project --> properties --> java Build path --> add external jar --> select your mysql jar from your pc.

refer this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vzCjvUwMXg

refer this code for login/signup fusing jsp + mysql 
https://github.com/Aksh0369/log_sin_jsp-MySql