# NullPointer Exception in MysqlDatasource in tomcat?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have configured mysqlDatasource in tomcat from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-from-eclipse) and [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+a+MySQL+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat). I have followed steps specified there. I have used following lines of code

```
class DataConnection {
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public DataConnection() {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        new DataConnection();
          Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();
          return con;
    }
}
```

But I still get a NullPointerException when connecting database.

1. Copied jar file into `mysql/lib` folder
2. Creating `context.xml` file and mention connection property.
3. In `WEB-INF/web.xml` I have mentioned

   jdbc/db
   javax.sql.DataSource

What am I doing wrong?

Note:I have created context.xml and mention the connection property. Finally manually copied into META-INF/context.xml.

Comment: check in the try block by putting breakpoint weather it is created or not.I think the problem in "ava:comp/env/jdbc/test"

Comment: yes.i have checked datasource value is null.

Comment: add e.printStackTrace(); in the catch block - I'm guessing that an exception is being thrown, but you don't see it because your catch block is empty. The exception should tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instance of `InitialContex` instead of `Context` and print sth

```
public DataConnection() {
            try {
                InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(dataSource name);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont know either you understand question or not.Context ctx = new InitialContext();Its working fine.when control comes next line it return null values only.datasource value is null.

Comment: what is the exception? after printing