# Issue with connecting JSP page to local MySQL database: wrong Database name

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

My project currently consists of a locally hosted set of JSP pages that connect to a mySQL database, that is also local.

I am trying to verify users that enter the site using the database. Yet the problem lies within the connection.

In the verification JSP page, I have this piece of code:

```
<%
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String database = "my_db";
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "password";

    try {


        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(pass);
        dataSource.setServerName(server);
        dataSource.setDatabaseName(database);
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=user&password=password");

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //connection = DriverManager.getConnection(server/*+database*/+"?user="+user+"&password="+pass);

        //DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        //connection=DriverManager.getConnection(server/*+database*/,user,pass);

        if(!connection.isClosed()){
            //do stuff
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        out.println("Cannot connect to database.<br>"+ex);
    }finally{//Release Resources
        if(resultSet!=null){
            try{resultSet.close();}catch(SQLException sqlEx){}
            resultSet = null;
        }

        if(statement != null){
            try{statement.close();}catch(SQLException sqlEx){}
            statement = null;
        }

        if(!connection.isClosed()){
            try{connection.close();}catch(SQLException sqlEx){}
            connection = null;
        }
    }
%>
```

I've tried various methods of connecting, yet none of them seem to work.

The first one (`Datasource`, not in comment) hits me with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Page output: http://prntscr.com/ff37x9

The second one (single `String` `DriverManager` connection) connects, but doesn't recognise the database. However, when I add `my_db` it tells me it doesn't find any database named "`my_db`".

Third and fourth are same as the second.

I can't understand what's malfunctioning. Should I be aware of something else?

Edit: The connection is needed only for this page, as the rest of the site is managed through the `session` object of Java

Thank you for your time.

Comment: With the Driver Manager you can connect, rigth? Wicht database user are you trying to connect?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a local database. This is the JDBC connection string I'm getting from MySQL Workbench: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root`

Comment: Yet it won't work; if I try to create a statement and execute it, it says it doesn't find a database.

Comment: Why are you using '?' at the url string?

Comment: @ThemistoklisGkasios you mentioned that you had NPE, can you please put the stacktrace here? In which class NPE was throw?

Comment: @Krismorte The '?' is for the `?user="user"` clause

Comment: @nikita_pavlenko Here is the output when I use Datasource: http://prntscr.com/ff37x9

Comment: @ThemistoklisGkasios look at my answer and try to put the database name directly on the URL connection with the DriveManager.

Comment: @Krismorte I am getting a very weird behaviour with adding/removing either the database or the `more stuff` code. Can I contact you directly?

Comment: @ThemistoklisGkasios yes, you can.

Comment: @ThemistoklisGkasios I send you an email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Krismorte for helping.

The database name can be found by typing `SELECT DATABASES;` in Workbench.

The schema I used was the same name of the database that I needed to access.

[MySQL Workbench PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ono0L.png)

Which is 'dip_db_schm'

In my case, the connection clause would be:

`connection=DriverManager.
    getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dip_db_schm","user","password");`

Answer (score 0):

Usually the datasource is being configured for JEE application via JNDI.

You can check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-jdbc-database-datasource-in-a-servlet-based-applicatio)

If you don't have a chance to write java code or to use JNDI and you can use only JSP, please consider at least using JSTL Tag library for SQL.

You can configure datasource and perform such action as in the following example:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix = "sql"%>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>JSTL sql:query Tag</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <sql:setDataSource var = "snapshot" driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
         user = "root"  password = "pass123"/>

         <sql:query dataSource = "${snapshot}" var = "result">
            SELECT * from Employees;
         </sql:query>

      <table border = "1" width = "100%">
         <tr>
            <th>Emp ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
         </tr>

         <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
            <tr>
               <td> <c:out value = "${row.id}"/></td>
               <td> <c:out value = "${row.first}"/></td>
               <td> <c:out value = "${row.last}"/></td>
               <td> <c:out value = "${row.age}"/></td>
            </tr>
         </c:forEach>
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

The only thing you need is to add JSTL tag library to your application classpath e.g. put [JSTL jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) to the same folder where you have MySQL driver jar.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish for this project. Is this the reason DataSource isn't working in my case?

Comment: @ThemistoklisGkasios no, Glassfish is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get a Connection with database directly on the URL connection

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDBName";
String user = "root";
String password = "root";
Class.forName(driver);
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, password);
```

Comment: Two things: Are you sure that the database my_db exists? The user has privileges on this database?

Comment: In workbench, I have [these two connections](http://prntscr.com/ff3zxq), that have the same password, and have the same user (root).