# Eclipse can't connect database

Tags: database, linux, eclipse

Is it possible to build desktop application whit small data base on linux/ubuntu? I have try eclipse+derby- not work, driver load, but can't connect to db. Eclipse +sqlite- not work too, No suitable driver. For a week from now i trying and can't connect to my db. If some1 have WORKING tutorial how to do this in ubuntu+eclipse, pls share. 1 week google, so please if some1 pass this to help me.

Now im using SQLite, i have load the sqlitejdbc-v051.jar in build path and use

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
```

but the result is: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:/home/vasil/MYDB

Comment: Any of those combinations would work, perhaps focus on one technology stack, and pose a *specific* question related to a problem you run into when using that stack.

Comment: All tutorials finish whit setup the db-ok. Using java to manipulate the data-fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [this site](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/start_toc.html)? It seems to be a fairly decent walkthrough. Is the db server that you are trying to connect to running and somewhere accessible to your application?

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816015/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby-localhost1527). It seems to be very similar to yours. I havn't used derby but I have used many other db servers. It sounds like you dont have the driver on your applications classpath.

Also, [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) might also be helpful. It shows how to use jdbc to connect to a db.

Comment: Have u done it? Because i have, and it not work for me. I can accesses the db from explorer, i can put data in, but if i try to make it whit java, no connection to db.

Comment: Just a note, be careful what you write. You dont want to give out information that could allow someone to connect to your db.

Comment: Nice, did you take a look at the edit I made to my answer? That explains it pretty well.