# JDBC Derby driver not found

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I've followed the JDBC tutorial at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html, and managed to build and create my own JDBC database without too much fuss. However now when trying to connect to the database from a java application I'm receiving the exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:*db
>   directory*

Then when trying to manually specify the JDBC driver using:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

I get the following exception error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

I am positive that that driver should have no issues loading as that is the driver specified in the tutorial and it had no issues creating the database using that driver. I've event tried adding the property " ;create=true" at the end of the connection statement to try and create a brand new database but I still receive the same exception error.

Please see my application code below.
Any help at all would be fantastic :).

```
package com.ddg;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class SQLConnect
{
    Connection Conn = null;
    String URL;
    String Username;
    String Password;

    public SQLConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        URL = "jdbc:derby:*directory name*";

        System.out.println("Created SQL Connect");
    }

    public void CreateConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            System.out.println("Successfully Connected");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Conn.close();
            System.out.println("Connection successfully closed");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SQLConnect sql = new SQLConnect();
        sql.CreateConnection();
        sql.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you specify the classpath?

Comment: Could you try `"jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true"`?

Comment: Add derby.jar to your classpath.

Comment: @lhuang I just tried your first suggestion and received the same error message about unable to find driver. Regarding your second suggestion, how do I add it to my project classpath? I've downloaded the Derby library files and added to my Windows Environment Variables Path.

Comment: If you are running Java via command line, you should add the JAR to CLASSPATH environment, not Path. If you are using eclipse, refer to http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: @lhuang, thanks heaps for the hint of adding the derby files to my lib folder. Tried that before but didn't work originally so gave up on that method, should have stuck with my instincts :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:db
>   directory

So your error can be caused by:

Driver is not loaded correctly or your `URL` is malformed. So at first you need to ensure that your `*.jar` is in classpath. Check it out.

Also try to change your `URL` to:

```
jdbc:derby://<path>/<databasename>;create=true
```

`create=true` will ensure that db will be created if does not exist.

### Update:

Look at this thead also: [SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816015/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby-localhost1527)

Comment: Thanks for the advise Sajmon. It turns out it was the fact that I was missing the required derby files from my referenced libraries (Classpath). Added them in and able to create a new DB and even link to my old one. Now just need to work out how to link to the database using an external IP address haha :)

Answer (score 7):

If you have this type of error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

and you are using `netbeans` then you have to follow these steps:

1. right click on library
2. choose add library option and from the list of libraries choose **"Java DB Driver"**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Java JDK comes with both

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Within eclipse add the following jars to the used JRE(JDK) or explicitly to your project.

```
[JDK]db/lib/derby.jar (EmbeddedDriver)
[JDK]db/lib/derbyclient.jar (ClientDriver)
```

For runtine you needed to made the appropriates jar available for your java application.

Answer (score 2):

You said you have followed the tutorial. In the tutorial you had to install JDBC driver.

> Installing a JDBC driver generally consists of copying the driver to
>   your computer, then adding the location of it to your class path.

After installing the driver you run

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

That is only possible if you messed the correct diver.

You have used

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

to load the driver

but should use

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Comment: How do you know Ice Phoenix is using a Derby **server**?

Comment: Because `ClassNotFoundException` for embedded driver, hence not using embedded.

Comment: But if he *is* using an embedded DB is **has** to use the embedded driver. If he was using a server connection he would have to *start* the server first which his post does not mention.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If changing the driver will fix the issue then my mission is completed.

Comment: Thanks for the advise guys, but as above, it turns out was just as simple as not referencing the drivers :). Really appreciate your input on this though, thanks.

Comment: But if he is **not** using a Derby server he won't be able to connect. So nothing would be solved.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guessed that OP has installed JDBC driver, as per p.3 of the tutorial OP has followed as it's said. And if OP is messed the embedded driver I guessed that no embedded driver in the library is used. But lately OP is commented here that don't understand p.3 of the tutorial. If did OP can't get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`. Do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

See the "Set DERBY_INSTALL" and "Configure Embedded Derby" section at https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure for details.

Derby is part of the JavaSE installation and I had setup environment variable `DERBY_HOME` instead of `DERBY_INSTALL` shown in the link.

```
C:\> set DERBY_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db
C:\> set CLASSPATH=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar;.
C:\> cd %DERBY_INSTALL%\bin
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db\bin> setEmbeddedCP.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** upon using the **ClientDriver**.
I used the latest Driver binaries, and that was the mistake.

At that time, the latest Driver binary was 10.15.1.3, right here: [Apache Site](https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html)

I'm on Java 8, and I use the Hibernate 5.4.2.Final.
Yet, the driver is compiled against the Java 9!

Answer (score 0):

I have been putting any needed jdbc driver at for example in the jre\lib\ext directory.
On my system that would be: X:\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\ext
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found recently that if you are using `jlink` to create a runtime, you may need to include additional jdk modules to allow the driver to instantiate.

In my case I needed to include the `java.naming` and `java.management` modules  within the image.

Answer (score 0):

So I encountered this error and it was quite an irritating and hectic task to resolve this. But in the end, I managed to find a perfect video that made me install derby from the start and guided me perfectly on how to install it. However, there is one more step after the video.

Watch this video if you have set up JavaFX packages and are able to run the program normally, but facing
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DBNAME;create=true" issue when trying to run with the database.

[Link to the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKiBsWbgrMw)

Now After this is set up you will now be able to start/stop the database (via the services tab) and will be able to connect with the DB. But the issue will still persist in trying to edit the DB.

***TO rectify this, follow the steps ->***

Right click on project     **--->**   Properties   **--->**   Libraries   **--->**   Click on '+' in Classpath   **--->**   Add jar/folder   **--->** Go to the lib folder inside the derby and select derbyclient.jar

**VERSIONS**

JAVA - 17.0.1, Netbeans - 12.6

HOPE IT HELPED,
THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an age old problem and caused me and others in this thread significant frustration.  Despite being successfully running tests in the Eclipse IDE test harness the application would fail to load the embedded drivers if called through a network connection.

With little evidence, I am going to suggest that the problem lies with Derby and the way it searches the `classpath` for the drivers and the delay causes a concurrency issue in that it can't find the drivers in time when searching outside its workspace.   I have repeated this test many time and can only achieve consistency if I create a `SharedLibraries` project within the programme's workspace and then adding this shared library to the `libraries` `classpath` as shown in the screen captures.

[image]

You do this by using `Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries`.  The only downside with this approach is that you don't know the source of the libaries and their versions, however this can be overcome by just adding the version number to the library files if this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many other options, but finally managed to fix this by simply **removing** the following line from my code:

```
Class.forName(driverClass);
```

I read somewhere that Derby uses internal jdbc driver which comes by default with the jdk.
I went through many jars which came along with the Derby installation, and looked for `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` class. Did not find it any of the jars.
Bit surprising, but it is true as it's working.
Note: You have to keep the Derby.jar on your classpath, and this answer is specifically for Embedded mode of derby.