# No Suitable Driver Found..still

Tags: java, jdbc, driver, derby, sqlexception

I'm getting the following error (Note: I am using Netbeans):

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:7001/LF_JHU_DERBY
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at randomtests.UFTest.main(UFTest.java:38)
```

The relevant part of my code is:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:7001/JP_JHU_DERBY", username, password);
```

I have the derby.jar file in my Java/Extensions directory--without that the embedded driver was not being found. So I have a few Q's:

1. Shouldn't it have a JDBC driver from the `Class.forName()` method? Why have problems all of  a sudden at `getConnection()`?
2. I thought I didn't even have to load a driver with the newer JDK's. I am using Netbeans and (succesfully, I think) set the netbeans.conf file to the latest JDK (with "netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home"). What am I missing?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15459364/877472

Comment: Regarding netbeans.conf: that configuration is only there to run NetBeans it is not necessarily the JDK used for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Derby can be run in two different modes:

1. as a network server
2. inside the JVM in memory.

The driver `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` can only handle in-memory databases. The URL for that has the format `"jdbc:derby:/path/to/database"`.

But your URL is one for a network server, which isn't handled by the embedded driver. To connect to a derby server, you have to use the driver class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`

Comment: First, thanks for helping! Now...I put ClientDriver in the Class.forName() and now it's throwing ClassNotFound…But shouldn't having derby.jar in Java/Extensions resolve this? (Like it did when I was using the embedded driver?)

Comment: @Jo.P: maybe your JDK was installed without JavaDB (it can be de-selected during installation - something I usually do as well)

Comment: It is part of the Derby "stuff", yes. So maybe you didn't add the correct jar file to your classpath. You need to add `derby.jar`

Comment: I just tried "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" and ClassNotFound…so maybe what you said is correct, although I still don't see how it relates to the derby stuff which I do have :(

Comment: @Jo.P `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` is part of the Java Runtime. That should *not* give you a ClassNotFoundException unless you are running Java **8** where the JDBC/ODBC bridge was removed.

Comment: Well, Java -version returns with: "java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)"
So…There's something really odd going on, then. Any ideas? 
Thanks for all your time/help, btw!