# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientDriver, have included derbyclient.jar in build path

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I have encountered this error in eclipse, attempting to connect to my database. 
I have looked at these suggestions:

[SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816015/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby-localhost1527)

[JDBC Derby driver not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459265/jdbc-derby-driver-not-found)

However they all seem to suggest including derbyclient.jar into build path for your project, which I have.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientDriver
    at datasource.DBConnection.getDBConnection(DBConnection.java:38)`

my database connection:

```
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database;create=true"; 
private static Connection getDBConnection(){
   try {

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver());

        Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
    System.out.println("Connection problem");
    return null;

}
```

Comment: needs to be on your classpath when you run it

Comment: Your code should never call `DriverManager.registerDriver`. That method is only to be called by JDBC drivers themselves.

Comment: The error means that the jar was present while compiling, but not when executing the application.