# Eclipse added jar to referenced libraries but still getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, derby, eclipse-classpath

Hi I'm following [this tutorial](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html?fbclid=IwAR1B6IVBRkcxBd6QW3_7M0z4FdcRgdU52Lxp0TRvne7lJXRqV7m1LtlxCcI) using eclipse. I've included the derby.jar and derbyclient.jar files and I can clearly see them appearing under referenced libraries. Oddly, I'm still geting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver even though the jar files are clearly there. I tried looking online but nothing were useful.

My steps of adding jar to referenced libraries: Right click project > properties > Java build path > Modulepath > Add External JARs. I've also tried adding it to Classpath instead of Modulepath and importing the package but either approaches doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC Derby driver not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459265/jdbc-derby-driver-not-found)

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file in your default package, deltete it (or learn about [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)).