# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees1

Tags: java, javadb

I researched on this problem but i did not find solution.

Following is my Code:

```
package database_console;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author SuperPc
 */
public class DBConnect {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try{
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees1","admin1","admin");
    }
    catch(SQLException err){
        System.out.println(err);

    }

}
```

}

When i run this Code then i get following

Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees1

[image: Screenshot of Services tab]

Please guide me that why this error coming and how Can i fix this.

Waiting for Replies.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you load the drivers using `Class.forName()`?

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816015/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby-localhost1527)

Answer (score 4):

Check for:

1. ***derbyclient.jar*** is on the class path.
2. Loading the driver class by

   ```
   Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
   ```