# Hive error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient"

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.1 and Hive 1.2.1 using instructions from tutorialspoint.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm

While starting hive, I'm getting error:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
.....
------

NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
.....
------

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
------
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
.....
```

Comment: ```No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true``` You don't have JDBC driver in your classpath

Comment: hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar is added in classpath. Getting error with that too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816015/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby-localhost1527

Comment: Tries this too. Does not help.