# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found jdbc:derby

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am having an issue with creating a database in my project. I've read in other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816015/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby-localhost1527), that I need to include this in my code:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

And so I did:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
 public static Connection getConnection() {
      try  {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Zadanie_3PU");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/iab;create=true", "", "");
        return con;
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("Database.getConnection() Error -->" + ex.getMessage());
          return null;
      }
  }
```

I've also made sure that I am loading the proper driver in my classpath:

[image]

And I also made sure that I have no typo in my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Zadanie_3PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.User</class>
    <class>model.Email</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/iab;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, this keeps throwing me the following error on my glassfish server, when I am trying to run it:

```
Info:   Database.getConnection() Error -->Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/iab;create=true
Error Code: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way you get the connection is a bit weird (why are you creating an `EntityManager`, doing nothing with it and then creating a new connection?), but other than that I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Please include the **full** exception in your question: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain