# Where to put META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver in web app

Tags: java, web-applications, jpa, jdbc

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) says "to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry: my.sql.Driver".

Don't webapps typically have a META-INF folder as a sibling of WEB-INF?  However, JPA specs are looking for persistence.xml in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/.

Which place is correct for services/java.sql.Driver?

By the way, I am getting ["No suitable Driver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-no-suitable-driver-exception-for-tomcat-5-5-postgres-and-jdbc) exception with it in both locations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not provide it yourself. The JDBC driver JAR file should already contain it. At least, if it's a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver. This is also explicitly mentioned in [javadoc of `DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> The `DriverManager` methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition [Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism. **JDBC 4.0 Drivers** must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of `java.sql.Driver`. For example, to load the `my.sql.Driver` class, the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
> my.sql.Driver
> ```
>
> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()` will continue to work without modification.

If yours doesn't have, then it's apparently not a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver. You'd need to explicitly load the driver yourself, or to upgrade to a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver, or just use a container managed `DataSource` (which offers more advantages as well, such as connection pooling).