# how to configure connection pooling in JPA/Hibernate application (Without Spring)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, connection-pooling

**Persistence.xml**

```
    <properties>
        <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.driver' value='org.postgresql.Driver' />
        <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.url'
            value='jdbc:postgresql://192.168.19.66:5432/service1' />
        <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.user' value='postgres' />
        <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.password' value='root' />
        <property name='hibernate.dialect' value='org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect' />
        <property name='hibernate.connection.shutdown' value='true' />
        <property name='hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' value='none' />
        <property name='hibernate.show_sql' value='false' />
        <property name='hibernate.format_sql' value='false' />
                    <!-- Connection Pooling -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="500" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="10000" />
    </properties>
```

**Exception**

```
[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4qw8wh4gndjoawud4|b81be4]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@5d1aef -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4qw8wh4gndjoawud4|b81be4]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - Continuing acquisition series. pending_acquires [5],  attempts_remaining: 20
[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4qw8wh4gndjoawud4|b81be4]-AdminTaskTimer] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@b66600: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@934847
[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4qw8wh4gndjoawud4|b81be4]-HelperThread-#0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

Getting exception **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver**.

As i look inside the source code, it is looking for the property "hibernate.connection.driver_class". Already, i mentioned the driver class in "javax.persistence.jdbc.driver".

I think i am not doing right way to configure the connection pool. The application is using hibernate 4.1.11(without spring), JPA2, Postgresql 9.1. There is no hibernate.cfg.xml.

**QUESTION**

- What is the way for configuring connection pool in Hibernate/JPA application.
- Already i provided in javax.persistence.jdbc.driver? whether the connection created by connection pool and JPA connection will be the same or different if i provide the `hibernate.connection.driver_class` property?

**NOTE**

- Postgresql driver is in classpath.
- If i remove lines after `<!-- Connection Pooling -->`, It runs. But if i add lines after `<!-- Connection Pooling -->` for connection pooling, I am getting this exception.

Comment: Is the postgreSQL driver in the classpath?

Comment: Yes. If i remove lines after <!-- Connection Pooling -->. It runs. But, if i add lines after <!-- Connection Pooling --> for connection pooling. I am getting this exception.

Comment: And what's the problem in setting the hibernate.connection.driver_class property?

Comment: Already i provided in javax.persistence.jdbc.driver? whether the connection created by connection pool and JPA connection will be the same or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899364/112500

I am able to resolve the problem.

And after apending this line to c3p0-config.xml

```
<property name="driverClass">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Back in the old days, you had to load the appropriate driver class using `Class.forName(org.postgresql.Driver.class)` construct. With JDBC 4.0 drivers it's no longer necessary - but you may give it a try.

Alternatively, try starting your application with `-Djdbc.drivers=org.postgresql.Driver`, it does virtually the same as `Class.forName` snippet, but doesn't require you to hardcode the driver class. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't help. Already i solved this problem which i published in answer.