# StandardContext Processing standard container startup takes longer the more libraries I add

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, deployment

I have a Java web app that uses Netbeans with Ant and Ivy for management and Tomcat as the server.
Tomcat version: 8.0.43

I have "Compile on save" checked so that every time I make a change to the code, the application redeploys.

So, I make a change, and then Netbeans automatically redeploys the app so that the changes can be seen in the browser when testing.

This redeploying used to take 1-3 seconds.

I recently added a large library with a lot of dependencies to my app ([Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/))

The result is now that redeploying when testing takes much longer (eg: 30 seconds).

Is there anything I can do in order to cut this redeploy time back down to a few seconds?

This is (the relevant part) printed to the log when the application redeploys (I set StandardContext logging to `FINE`):

> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:52.996 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with
>   name [] has started
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:53.055 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Sending
>   application stop events
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:53.125 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal Processing
>   standard container shutdown
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:53.171 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resetContext resetContext
>   Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:53.171 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal Stopping
>   complete
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:53.171 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Starting ROOT
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:08:53.627 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Processing
>   standard container startup
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:09:11.856 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setPublicId Setting
>   deployment descriptor public ID to 'null'
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:09:12.200 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Configuring
>   application event listeners
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:09:12.405 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Starting
>   completed
>
> 19-Jun-2019 12:09:12.405 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-4] 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [] is completed

As you can see, the long wait time occurs when `StandardContext.reload` is called.
Specifically, between:

> Processing standard container startup

And

> Setting deployment descriptor public ID to 'null'

This corresponds to the code between lines **4325** and **4467** in the [`StandardContext.start()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java.html) source code.

But I'm still not sure what the cause is in this portion of code.

Extra info:

- The `jar` files that my app depends on are in the `libraries` folder.
- All `jar` files that are downloaded by the dependency manager are stored in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Nothing is changing in my `libraries` folder and therefore I would think that, after the initial addition of the library, there shouldn't be any extra time required for the redeploy.

How can I change my set up so that I can redeploy the app in a few seconds again?

Or, is this redeploy time inevitable when including such a large amount of libraries?

Comment: Apache Tika: https://tika.apache.org/

Comment: Ok, I added it. I figured it's the size of the library that's causing the slow-down, not the contents of the library; that's why I thought it wasn't really relevant to the question. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's probably the size rather than the content, but knowing which library you were using helps to reproduce your problem more closely - that's all. Also FYI, questions should be freestanding - it shouldn't be necessary to read the comments to obtain relevant information - so that's why it helps to update the question.

Comment: I added some more detailed debug log messages as well if that helps...

Comment: @skomisa Is it expected for the reload time to be this long if I include such a large amount of libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the jars from the added library to the property:

> tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip

In Tomcat's `catalina.properties` file (found in the `conf` folder).

There are many questions that explain this issue, eg: [How to fix JSP compiler warning: one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375673/how-to-fix-jsp-compiler-warning-one-jar-was-scanned-for-tlds-yet-contained-no-t)