# Access to MySQL using Java Servlet?

Tags: mysql, jsp, web-applications, servlets, insert

The Solution:

I added this code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

brfore

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "root", "root");
```

Thank you all for reply my question

====================

I have problem, I try to insert data into mysql db using servlet, **but I couldn'y access to MySQL**

- Database name: test
- Table name: test
- I already added jdbc connector to the project library
- I'm using JDK 1.7, NetBeans 7.3, MySQL 5.6, Tomcat 7.0, Connector/J 5.1.24

**1- this is "form action" in sign_up.jsp page:**

```
<form action="RegisterUser" method="post">
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</form>
```

**2- this is RegisterUser.java servlet:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/RegisterUser"})
public class RegisterUser extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {

    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "root");
        Statement s = (Statement) con.createStatement();

        String name = "Hassan3";
        int phone = 123456;

        String insert = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('\" + name + \"', \" + phone + \")";

        s.executeUpdate(insert);

        s.close();
        con.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new SecurityException("Class not found " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

**3- the exception result:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Class not found java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test

type Exception report

message Class not found java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Class not found java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    RegisterUser.processRequest(RegisterUser.java:66)
    RegisterUser.doPost(RegisterUser.java:173)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 logs.
```

**4- But when I use same code but in java file "without servlet or web app" it's working correctly:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "root");
        Statement s = (Statement) con.createStatement();

        String name = "Hassan4";
        int phone = 8985895;

        String insert = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('" + name + "', " + phone + ")";

        s.executeUpdate(insert);

        s.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("done");
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new SecurityException("Class not found " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

so what is problem with servlet? **Why the code works with java app. but it doesn't work with web app.?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `Class not found java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test`

It means When you are running it from Web Application, JRE could not find Class in the Classpath.

If this code works in your Standalone it means you need to have a JAR file somewhere containing c`om.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class (so called **JDBC** driver). This JAR needs to be visible in Tomcat. So, I would suggest placing `mysql-jdbc.jar` at a physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project.

Alternatively, you can add Third party libraries like JDBC driver here using

> Right Click Project Name--> Properties

[image]

from your `NetBeans` IDE

Then restarting Tomcat should work.

Second, you don't need

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
```

in your Servlet.

Answer (score 1):

David is right and i want to add, you can also install the driver by pasting the jar file in the the installation folder of java.

```
\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext
```

Well i dont like mysql very much and always use Mssql with a windows server 2008. This is the code i use for that, i might be your answer since mysql connection works pretty much the same as sql.

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName="+database+";user="+user+";password="+password);
```

Comment: I already added the connector jar to this dir (\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext) and after that add it to mu project in NetBeans (Libraries->Add JAR/Folder)

also I tried to add it to this dir (WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: Well i dont like mysql very much and always use Mssql with a windows server 2008. This is the code i use for that, i might be your answer since mysql connection works pretty much the same as sql, see edit of my post

Answer (score 0):

First, you should put that into a persistance layer.

1) Ensure that your JDBC driver is in place. Copy it into your classpath, e.g. /WEB-INF/lib directory. Link: [MySQL JDBC Driver Download Page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

2) Check your connect string: `jdbc:mysql://<server>:<port>/<database>`, looks like the port is missing. Try `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test`

Comment: MySQL works in port 3306, and the same code (char by char) works with JAVA App. correctly, the problem only when I use it in servlet "WEB App."
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Where did you copy the driver? What ist the name of that file?

Comment: (mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar) I copy it to (\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext)
Also I tried to copy it to (/WEB-INF/lib)
I think no problem with connector file or with localhost:3306, 'Coz it's working in JAVA Application, the problem only in (WEB Application using Servlet)

Comment: Did you try to clean, republish and restart the tomcat?