# No Suitable Driver found Postgres JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I am receiving a "no suitable driver found" error when I test my web service on tomcat. I have the JDBC .jar in the lib folder as various tutorials says to do. Here is my code:

```
public class PostDBConnection {

 PreparedStatement st;
 ResultSet rs;
 Connection con;
 DataSource ds;
 InitialContext cxt;

 String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/UptonDB";
 String user = "*****";
 String password = "*******";
 String query = "";
 StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public String getInfo(){

    int size = 0;  


    try {

        cxt = new InitialContext();     
        ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/UptonDB");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{

        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgres.Driver");


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT VERSION()");         
        rs = st.executeQuery();


        while(rs.next())
            {
                    response.append(rs.getString(1));

            }               
        }     

    catch(SQLException exc)
        {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostDBConnection.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, exc.getMessage(), exc);
        } 
    finally {
        try {
           if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostDBConnection.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

Also here are the web.xml and context.xml files I created by following instructions on the Tomcat website:

```
 <resource-ref>
<description>PostgreSQL Data Source </description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/UptonDB</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

web.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <Context>  
   <Resource name="jdbc/UptonDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="30" maxActive="80"   
    maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="*****" password="*******"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/UptonDB" useUnicode="true"
    characterEncoding="utf-8" characterSetResults="utf8"/>
   </Context>
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: where did you get the postgresql JDBC driver from? Can you add the link to that one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The infamous "No suitable Driver" exception for Tomcat 5.5, Postgres, and JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-no-suitable-driver-exception-for-tomcat-5-5-postgres-and-jdbc)

Comment: In which lib directory did you put it? Why do you use DriverManager since you want to get the connection from a Tomcat DataSource?

Comment: I agree with JB Nizet: using a DataSource JNDI lookup and the DriverManager does not make any sense.

Comment: I am completely new to this so what should I be doing instead? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the Driver class and get the connection from DriverManger, the Datasource takes care of this for you. Just remove this line: Class.forName("org.postgres.Driver"); and than get the connection from the Datasource you have already looked up in the code, so remove: con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); and than: con = ds.getConnection(); and use the connection. Remove all the unused code from stance variables. 
Study this page: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper Driver name is **org.postgresql.Driver** and not org.postgres.Driver

Update:

Check this page give it a bit of study and you should be fine
:)
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Then instead of using DriverManager, you should just do a lookup(you did already) and get a connection from the DataSource(You can remove pwd, user, and other unused stuff from your code):

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/UptonDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will update with results when I apply the changes

Comment: Hi, I did an update to my answer so you might understand how to do it better.