# How do you get the driver and executors to load and recognize the postgres driver in EMR with spark-submit?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, hadoop, driver, amazon-emr

**BACKGROUND**
I am trying to run a spark-submit command that streams from Kafka and performs a JDBC sink into a postgres DB in AWS EMR (version 5.23.0) and using scala (version 2.11.12). The errors I see are

```
INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) on <master-public-dns-name>, executor 1: java.sql.SQLException (No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://... 

ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@44dd5258 is aborting.
19/06/20 06:11:26 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@44dd5258 aborted.
```

**HYPOTHESIS PROBLEM**
I think the error is telling me that the jdbc postgres driver cannot be found on the executors, which is why it cannot sink to postgres.

**PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS**
I have already done the following:

1. Identified my driver in my structured streaming job as `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")`
2. added `--jars postgresql-42.1.4.jar \` to my spark-submit job in order to send the jars to the driver and executors. In this attempt, this postgres driver jar exists in my local /home/user_name/ directory
3. Also tried `--jars /usr/lib/spark/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar \` to my spark-submit job, which is the location that spark in emr finds all the jars for execution
4. started my spark-submit job with `spark-submit --driver-class-path /usr/lib/spark/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar:....`
5. added the `/usr/lib/spark/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar` to the spark.driver.extraClassPath, spark.executor.extraClassPath, spark.yarn.dist.jars, spark.driver.extraLibraryPath, spark.yarn.secondary.jars, java.library.path, and to the System Classpath in general
6. My jdbc connection, while working in Zeppelin, does not work in spark-submit. It is `jdbc:postgres://master-public-dns-name:5432/DBNAME"`

**EXPECTED RESULT:**
I expect my executors to recognize the postgres driver and sink the data to the postgres DB.

**PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS:**
I've already used the following suggestions to no avail:

[Adding JDBC driver to Spark on EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756335/adding-jdbc-driver-to-spark-on-emr)

[No Suitable Driver found Postgres JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913253/no-suitable-driver-found-postgres-jdbc)

[No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696688/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcpostgresql-192-168-1-85432-nexentasearch)

Answer (score 0):

use `-- packages org.postgresql:postgresql:<VERSION>`