# Spring JDBC Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I wonder if any one could help me with this. I encountered an issue when I tried writing code with Spring JDBC. When I ran the server, I got the message like I mentioned in the title. I have google it and someone said that you should import ojdbc.jar. However, I have already imported it. Here comes my code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.13:1521/orcl" />
    <property name="username" value="Hibernate" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Please kindly suggest if I have done something wrong. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make sure that ojdbc.jar is in your CLASSPATH when application is running. For example, if you are creating a web app - ojdbc.jar should be present in WEB-INF/lib of your WAR file.

Comment: @SergeyMakarov Hi Sergey, thank you for your quick response. However, I am just testing it in MyEclipse...

Comment: You need to setup build path for your Eclipse project, this may help - http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: @SergeyMakarov Thank you again for your reply. However, when I replaced the class content with this: "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" it works well. Pretty strange.

Comment: are you using any build tools like maven ?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that you have **ojdbc.jar** gets added into your class path. If you want, you can also double check it by opening **.classpath** file and look for **ojdbc.jar** entry. If you don't have it, download it from the the maven repo as mentioned below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
.......

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: @jagadesh, isn't oracle jdbc.jar covered under oracle license and that's why it is not on maven? Also, will I come under trouble if I'm using this for office work?

Comment: @kainix, yes you did have issues using in work place. You still have an option to have it installed as a maven artifact to your repo and use it. However, it come back to the same question that is it a right way of having access to these license jars? That I can't have an answer for.

Answer (score 6):

Download the ojdbc jar from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

Put `ojdb6.jar` in some folder in your project (let's use lib).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Then do :

```
mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=path/to/ojdbc6.jar \
-DgroupId=com.oracle \
-DartifactId=ojdbc6 \
-Dversion=11.2.0 \
-Dpackaging=jars
```

Answer (score 3):

I just put ojdbc6.jar in apache tom cat installation directory in lib directory

D:\TOOLS\apache tomcat server\Tomcat 8.0\lib

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven as your build tool, then add this below dependency. Make sure you have the correct version of ojdbcXX.jar file corresponding to the database version. For me, I have an Oracle 11g database, hence I am using ojdbc6.jar.

Step 1) Add dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
   <version>6</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>C:\Users\AkhileshPC\Downloads\ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Step 2) Install the ojdbcXX.jar in your Maven local repository.

`Command > mvn install:install-file "-Dfile =Downloads\ojdbc6.jar" "-DgroupId=com.oracle" "-DartifactId=ojdbc6" "-Dversion=11.2.0.1" "-Dpackaging=jar"`

[Setting up maven local repository image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2agB0.jpg)

Step 3) Make sure your ojdbcXX.jar file is available in the WEB-INF\lib folder of the corresponding project in the .metadata folder.

My case:

`C:\Users\AkhileshPC\JavaSpring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\1007_Spring_Mvc_App_Crud\WEB-INF\lib`

[web-inf folder path Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ifD0.jpg)

Once all three of these steps are completed, the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was setting the scope to `runtime`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy ojdbc6.jar into tomcat/lib folder as in a picture below.
 [example tomcat/lib/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEiYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:schema_name/123456@192.168.0.13:1521:orcl" />
    <property name="username" value="Hibernate" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

If you use Spring Boot 2 (I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE, Oracle database 12c), `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:schema_name/123456@192.168.0.13:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=Hibernate
spring.datasource.password=123456
```

(You must have `ojdbc7.jar` in classpath)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in InteliJ like this:

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> click on '+' (add new) -> point to the ojdbc.jar path under file system (previously downloaded manually or using some build tool)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use idea add ojdbc to lib ,but it is not valid.

My final solution is to add ojdbc.jar to tomcat lib dir then restart it.

No fatal error