# Setting up a JDBC data source and connection pool

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have followed every step in the tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html but the data source and connection pool are not displayed on the Server Resources node.

after completing all the other steps and deploying the project, i get the following error...

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"

root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"

Comment: can you share you code for better understanding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)