# Connecting to apache phoenix using JDBC and Java

Tags: java, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a small java program in which I try to establish a connection to a remote Phoenix server I have running.

```
package jdbc_tests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PhoenixTest {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver";
    static final String IP = "<placeholder>"
    static final String PORT = "<placeholder>"
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:phoenix://" + IP + ":" + PORT + "/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database..");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

            System.out.println("Creating statement...");

            st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT DISTINCT did FROM sensor_data";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()) {
                String did = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println("Did found: " + did);
            }

            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (st != null)
                    st.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            } // nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } // end finally try
        } // end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

When I try to run my program I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix://<ip>:<port>/
```

I have added the following jar from the Apache Phoenix distribution:

```
phoenix-4.9.0-HBase-1.2-client.jar
```

which matches my Phoenix and Hbase vesions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your URL is wrong: you should remove the `//`. See also http://phoenix.apache.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav I disaggree

Comment: A couple of simple google searches were tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the name of your database and also the URL seams not correct:

```
"jdbc:phoenix://" + IP + ":" + PORT + "/" + DB_NAME
//--------------------------------------------^^
```

You have to try with this URL Instead :

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:<IP>:<port>:/<DB_NAME>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding the DB_NAME didn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you get any other error when you use the DB_NAME or it still the same @Zeliax ?

Comment: Still got the same error message.. `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix://<ip>:<port>/<db_name>`

Comment: Yes. This worked out and is the solution! However I did not need to use the DB_Name part. So I used `"jdbc:phoenix:<IP>:<PORT>/`. I do however face another problem after this, but that will be for another post :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

URL should not contains "//" , it should be like this: 
jdbc:phoenix:192.168.4.251:2181:/hbase-unsecure