# Why ServletContextListener does not see database?

Tags: java, servlets

I using my implementation `ServletContextListener` for writing in servlet context my object for work with database. In unit test my database handler work but same code in `ServletContextListener` throw `java.sql.SQLException`.

This is my database handler test which create Connection to DB and it's work. No exception no problem. All ok:

```
@Test
public void whenCreateDBJoinInstanceThenResultOfMethodGetDBExecutorNotNull() throws SQLException {
    final DBJoint db = new DBJointHandler("database_scripts", "authentication_database");
    Assert.assertNotNull(db);
    db.closeConnection();
}
```

This is use same `DBJoint` which create Connection to database:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

        final ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

        servletContext.setAttribute("db", new DBJointHandler("database_scripts", "authentication_database"));

    }
    ...
}
```

And this my result:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/user_storage
```

And place which throw this Exception:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        return DriverManager.getConnection(
                properties.get("url"),
                properties.get("username"),
                properties.get("password")
        );

}
```

This is exactly the same code which in test. When i run test then it's ok. When i use `ServletContextListener` it's Exception.

What wrong? How fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: It is a problem with the JDBC driver not being loaded. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911487/3586783) for tips on how to make sure the JDBC driver is loaded.

Comment: @pacifier21 that Q&A is obsolete. It is no longer necessary to use Class.forName(...) to load JDBC drivers (since Java 5 in fact).

Comment: You need to ensure that the PostgreSQL JDBC driver is available for your application by either including it in your WEB-INF/lib directory (assuming a WAR deployment) or installing it as part of your server (whatever that may be).

Comment: Fair enough, but that doesn't change the fact that it is not finding the JDBC driver for postgresql. The driver needs to be in the proper path to get loaded into the environment.

Comment: @Steve C I add jar of postgres in `WEB-INF/lib/` and `apache-tomcat/lib/` but same result. I Try call `Class.forName("com.example.jdbc.Driver");` in `ContextListener` but i had ClassNotFoundException. JDBCDriver is lost(((

Comment: Exactly which jar did you add and where did it come from? Also, what version of Java are you using?