# java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource

I have this code and i compile it with eclipse

```
import java.sql.*;


 public class ConnectSQL {

  private static String Connect() {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 Connection connection = null;
  String ok;
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {

Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://192.168.0.10:3306/basededatos", "root", "passwd");
    ok ="Connection succed";
}
   catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 ok= "not ok";
}
 return ok;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
 String mensage;
    mensage = Connect(); 
  System.out.println(mensage);
 }

 }
```

`
When i execute this it give me an error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver not ok  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   lib.ConnectSQL.Connect(ConnectSQL.java:14)    at
>   lib.ConnectSQL.main(ConnectSQL.java:27)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TiKL.png)
What its wrong??

Thx
Regards

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/ : The driver lib (mysql-connector-java.jar) is missing in your (runtime) classpath.

Comment: Thx i copy the driver and edit the path; but it isnt work. I dont understand why

Comment: Hi guys i resolve my problem on eclipse we must to add a external jar to de jre lib; on linux terminal we have to execute "root@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt# pwd
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt
root@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt# javac -cp lib/mariadb-java-client-2.1.0.jar ConnectSQL.java
^[[Aroot@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt# java -cp '.:lib/mariadb-java-client-2.1.0.jar' ConnectSQL
Connection succed
root@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt#"