# display the data from the database

Tags: mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

new.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP List Users Records</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource
        var="headway"
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/headway"
        user="root" password="toor"
    />

    <sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="$ {headway}">
        SELECT * FROM head;
    </sql:query>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <caption><h2>List of users</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Profession</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.salary}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.designation}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hi

I am trying to display the data from the database.
but it shows error like that:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /new.jsp at line 20

```
    user="root" password="toor"
 />

<sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="$ {headway}">
    SELECT * FROM head;
 </sql:query>
```

Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for $ {headway}"

but actually there is database name is headway

table name is head;

```
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | name  | salary | designation |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | srinu |  50000 | test        |
|  2 | srinu | 500000 | devel       |
|  3 | pawan | 100000 | net         |
|  4 | ravi  |   2000 | .net        |
|  5 | ramya |  22222 | tester      |
|  6 | srinu |      0 | sql         |
|  7 | srinu | 200000 | test        |
|  8 | srinu |   1000 | java        |
|  9 | srinu |  11111 | html        |
| 10 | srinu |  11111 | html        |
| 11 | vv    |  29999 | hg          |
| 12 | s     |    147 | aa          |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: hey guys,I always see your question recently,I think you need to improve the basic coding knowledge

Comment: actually i am new to the spring mvc

Comment: first, you need to response your previous questions so that other's work is not in vain.

Comment: for you question,you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found

Answer (score 0):

Your error says `No suitable driver found for` which means it is not able to find the source library that is to be used to connect to the `DB`. Find the suitable driver that will be required to your `DB` and add that to your projects and servers classpath.