# JdbcRowSet returns SQL Exception

Tags: java

Please, help me with the **RowSetProvider**, it throws an SQL exception

> (No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306)

while **Drivermanager.getConnection()** works OK.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zoo?serverTimezone=UTC", "hbstudent",
            "hbstudent");
    System.out.println(con.getCatalog()); // <-- works OK

    // ****************************************************

    JdbcRowSet rs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJdbcRowSet();

    rs.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zoo?serverTimezone=UTC");
    rs.setUsername("hbstudent");
    rs.setPassword("hbstudent");
    rs.setCommand("select 1");
    rs.execute(); //<-- Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zoo?serverTimezone=UTC

}
```

Comment: is the MySql jdbc driver on your runtime classpath?

Comment: Maybe the driver doesn't support JdbcRowSet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: @Reimeus  After adding Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") and checking "Java Build Path" nothing changed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How to find if a driver supports JdbcRowSet, I'm using mysql-connector-java-8.0.15, suppose it is the newest ont

Comment: No idea, check the documentation I guess.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209063/does-mysql-connector-j-driver-implement-jdbcrowset-interface?noredirect=1#comment99060248_56209063

Answer (score 0):

I don't pretend to be introducing effective solution, but recently I faced very same problem with creating **JdbcRowSet** and **CachedRowSet** objects while using Java SE Development Kit 11.0.1 + MySQL Server 8.0.16 + Connector / J 8.0.16 driver.

After updating JDK for the latest version 12.0.1, the problem just disappeared.

P.S.

But be ready, after successfully creating **JdbcRowSet** object you might face another kind of problem while trying to update it. See ["java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is not updatable" with JdbcRowSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090869/java-sql-sqlexception-resultset-is-not-updatable-with-jdbcrowset) for details.