# "java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is not updatable" with JdbcRowSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rowset

I want to use RowSet Interface implement update,But I meet some error.

I’ve tried on following code:

```
// Load the JDBC driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Driver loaded");

RowSetFactory rsFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
JdbcRowSet rowSet = rsFactory.createJdbcRowSet();

rowSet.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
rowSet.setUsername(USERNAME);
rowSet.setPassword(PASSWORD);

// make rowset updateable
rowSet.setReadOnly(false); 
rowSet.setType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
rowSet.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

rowSet.setCommand("Select * from money");
rowSet.execute();

rowSet.absolute(3);
rowSet.updateInt("balance", parseIntBalance); //update third rows balance label to 5000
rowSet.updateRow();
```

Following is error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is not updatable
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.checkTypeConcurrency(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:4139)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.updateInt(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:2306)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.updateInt(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:2735)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it directly on a result set instead of a `RowSet`?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue using MySQL Connector/J version 8.0.16. The issue does not occur with MySQL Connector/J version 5.1.47.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No, because the job request is to use rowset

Comment: @GordThompson thank you,But why can't MySQL Connector/J version 8.0.16 be executed?

Comment: It looks like a bug was introduced when the version 5.x code was tweaked for version 8.x.

Comment: @Gord Thompson thank you very much!