# How to set driver for postgres?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have spring boot application, where i want to test batch insert to different data bases. I have pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

And code in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "setdb/{url}/{schema}/{login}/{password}")
public String setDB(@PathVariable(name = "url") String url,
                    @PathVariable(name = "schema") String schema,
                    @PathVariable(name = "login") String login,
                    @PathVariable(name = "password") String password) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+url+"?currentSchema="+schema;
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
    return String.format("url: %s\nlogin: %s\npassword: %s", url, login, password);
}
```

When i tried to do this i have error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-02-03T09:06:46.800+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432?currentSchema=app",
    "path": "/setdb/127.0.0.1:5432/app/postgres/qwerty"
}
```

How can i fix it? Set the driver programmatically?

Comment: Try loading the postgress Driver first? Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

Comment: @Worthless that hasn't been necessary for years.

Comment: i tried. does not work

Comment: Most likely the driver jar isn't being included for some reason. Generate a war and check if the jar is included in the libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: Is `app` a schema or a database? And if it's really a schema, then why aren't you providing a database name in the URL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's so nice of MySQL to make it "easier" by treating databases and schemas as the same thing.

Comment: @Kayaman Depending on the context, explicit driver loading may still be necessary (eg if the driver is in a WAR, and not on the initial classpath).

Comment: You shouldn't use `DriverManager.getConnection` in Spring Boot, but instead use a datasource. See [How-to Guide: Data Access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-data-access)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ah, that's a good point (re: classloaders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://**localhost:5432**/**postgres**

in your URL you need to add host and db name

url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+url+"?currentSchema="+schema;

**url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+url+"/"+schema** use this url

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the driver is in your classpath the error can also stem from a wrong connection URL.
Check your URL Syntax, it should be either of

- jdbc:postgresql:database
- jdbc:postgresql://host/database
- jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database

So if app is the db you should do:

> jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/app

If app is a schema in a DB you still have to specify your DB in the URL

> jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DBNAME?currentSchema=app

Answer (score -2):

well what I did to test this is created an empty mvn project

```
spring init --name=postgres-demo --dependencies=web,jpa,postgresql 
postgres-test
```

and to the application properties under resources added this & it works for me:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_test
spring.datasource.username= rajtest
spring.datasource.password=

# dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: The OP already has the JDBC driver as a dependency, and given the code shown is not using a datasource.

Comment: so basically rather than doing it in the controller added it in the app properties & that does it.

Comment: You are missing my point, the OP is currently not `DriverManager.getConnection`, so all this config you're showing will not solve his problem, unless you also explain what he needs to change in his code to make use of that config.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel got it