# How to connect to MySql 8.0 database using Eclipse Database Management Perspective

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-8.0, eclipse-dtp

I wanted to connect to local MySql 8.0 database using Eclipse database tools. But while setting up new database connection profile, I could not find Driver Template for MySql 8.0 . The list only contains Template profile upto MySql JDBC Driver 5.1 . So How can newer version of MySql like 8.0 in my case can be connected using eclipse DTP tools

[image: This is screenshot of New Driver Definition window]

Comment: Have you tried using the highest version available? Likely it will work.

Comment: It's the highest version as far as I know

Comment: No, I meant that in that Eclipse screen the highest available is 5.1, try using that even if your MySQL version is 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select version 5.1 from the list. MySQL JDBC driver version 5.1 (i.e. `Connector/J 5.1`) is compatible with `MySQL 8.0`. Given below is an excerpt from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html:

> Connector/J 5.1 is a Type 4 pure Java JDBC driver, which conforms to
> the JDBC 3.0, 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2 specifications. It provides
> compatibility with all the functionality of MySQL, including 5.6, 5.7
> and 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I did the followings,
[image]

select the MYSQL JDBC Driver 5.1 and change the Driver name to unique name as below,
[image]

Next I removed the existing jar and include the correct MYSQL jar file in the jar list,

[image]

Important - Remove the 5.1 jar else it will give you and error

finally setup the Database connection database name, user name and password

[image]

And Now Click OK!!!