# How to resolve java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for SQLServer 2008 R2?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have a sample code to connect to SQLServer is given below :

```
Connection conn=null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     conn= DriverManager.getConnection(" jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Test" );

    System.out.println("connected");


} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I execute this code, I'm getting an exception given below :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at JDBCSample.main(JDBCSample.java:14)
```

Comment: Why is there a space before `jdbc` in your connection url?  And it should be `database` not `databaseName` last time I did this, but that could be synonymous or have changed in versions

Comment: Use the site search box, there are many questions with that same error such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found). Update your question with how your situation is different and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jar for SQLServer is not supporting or typo in the connection string.

Download SQLServer 2008 R2 compatible jar from here :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Steps :

- Click on Download :

[image]

- Select `sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar.gz` or `sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.zip` if shown.

[image]

- Click on Next to start downloading.
- After downloading, extract the content. Now, go into `sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre8` or `sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre7`and copy the jar based on the jdk you are using.

[image]

Add the jar in the classpath of the project.

Fix this line

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(" jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test" );
```

to this by removing space.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test");
```

Comment: Would this not result in a `ClassNotFoundException` from the `Class.forName` call if it wasn't included on the classpath?

Comment: Edited answer would now be my best guess on how to resolve this.  I'll upvote if the user in question (@nazanin n) confirms it resolves the issue for them.

Comment: I did what you said but I still get the error @AnishB.

Comment: @nazaninn Did you change the connection string ?

Comment: @nazaninn Check for driver. I added the link. follow that link and download the appropriate jar.

Comment: @AnishB. I do not know which version is a correct one i am using sql server 2008R2

Comment: @nazaninn I'm checking. Basically, they are removing support for older versions.

Comment: @nazaninn I got the jar.

Comment: @AnishB. the one in the answer ?? thank you so much

Comment: @nazaninn I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @nazaninn I have updated my answer. This much I found for you.

Comment: @nazaninn Is this helpful ??

Comment: @nazaninn Please mark this as accepted answer and upvote if it was helpful ?

Comment: @AnishB. actually it was not helpful I used them and I sill get the error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need an JDBC driver supporting your type and version of your SQL Database. Maybe your version of the driver is the wrong one?
You should check this out: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/javasqlsqlexception-no-suitable-driver-mysql-jdbc-localhost.html
What is the DriverManager doing at lines 689 and 270?

Comment: my SQL server is 2008 r2  which version I should use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15
Check out the "SQL version compatibility" I think thats what you are looking for.