# No suitable driver found inside Docker

Tags: java, scala, docker, jdbc

So I have this application that connects to DB via simple JDBC written in Scala. Everything works fine until I'm trying to run it inside Docker container, there I'm getting the infamous `Error during processing of request: 'No suitable driver found for "jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5439/dev"`
I've built a fat jar and when I'm running it on my machine - everything works fine, but the same fat jar that has been put inside docker container via

```
FROM java:8

COPY target/scala-2.13/loader-0.1.jar /fatjar.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "fatjar.jar"]
```

just can't connect. When I'm trying to debug - I see that driver is there:

```
  val dm = DriverManager.getDrivers()

  while (dm.hasMoreElements()) {
    println(dm.nextElement().getClass())
  }
```

spits out the same output both on my machine and inside docker. Can anyone point me to a possible piece that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `fatjar` has a valid Postgres driver in it? Maybe it works on your machine because you installed that driver on a global location that is always on the classpath.

Comment: debugging print spits me the following list inside docker:
`➜  loader : ✗ docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file .testenv loader
19:48:16.257 [example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
class org.h2.Driver
class org.postgresql.Driver
class com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver
19:48:16.991 [main] INFO Main$ - Server online at http://localhost:8080/`
which is the same as on my machine. i was also thinking that it might catching up driver somewhere on my machine, but dunno, i have it in my sbt dependencies and i don't exclude anything

Comment: This post might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found

Comment: check your db url, it might be reason

Comment: Your JDBC url seems to be missing the database name, also 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address to connect to; if you want to connect to the local machine, use 127.0.0.1

Comment: sorry, i've cut it out initially, added back to avoid confusion. i've tried using different urls, like some open RDS with DNS and again, it works fine on my machine, but not inside docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in the end the issue was fixed by moving from redshift driver (I need to actually connect to redshift) to postgres one `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1"` and with that in dependencies and having actually postgresql conn string I was able to solve my issue.