# I can not initiate derby schema

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, derby

when i run $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby

the output is

```
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:   APP
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to get schema version.
Underlying cause: java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
SQL Error code: 0
Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

Comment: Summary of reasons for this exception from a different context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911487/13447

Comment: Are you certain that your Derby Network Server is up and running on port 1527?

Comment: @BryanPendleton Hive should start an embedded Derby on its own. Error says driver isn't found